# State vs action

Tags: word-meaning

In a unit about **until** and **by** in the PEU says:

> We use **until** to talk about situation or state that will continue up to
>   a certain moment. We use **by** to say that an action or event happen at
>   or before a future moment.

Are there formal differences between *state* and *action*? I think when we talk about something we can refer to state as perhaps longer action and to an event say that an action is shorter regarding to the longer action. So I suppose we always talk about these two action together. It is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked up Swan's PEU, it's Topic 602.6, "until and by: states and actions".

I've come up with these examples:

> The sky will *be blue* **until** 9 p.m.
>   The sky will *turn black* **by** 10 p.m.

"The sky will *be blue*" describes a state. The sky is not doing any active *action* to keep its blue color.

"The sky will *turn black*" describes an action: the sky is changing its color. At some moment before 10 p.m. it will become black.

But I guess the boundary between *state* and *action* is blurred:

> The sky will *be turning black* **until** 10 p.m.  (here, a slow action is seen as a state or condition, IMHO)
>   The sky will *be black* **by** 10 p.m. (here, an action is implied but not named)

Comment: Let me ask you one more question. When you said _I've came up with these examples..._, what was the meaning of _came up_ you mentioned? I've found http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/come-up and suspect it's _to be mentioned or talked about in conversation_

Comment: @DmitryFucintv ---  [Come up with](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/come_up_with) - "to invent, create, or think of" - "I don't know the answer, but I might be able to come up with a good guess."

Comment: @DmitryFucintv - and I've committed an error in writing it as "I've came up": one should use only "come" (Past Participle) after **have**. "I've come up with examples".

Answer (score 2):

The state represents a condition of something.
Example, the car will continue to idle until the gas tank is empty.
You may stay up until 11 PM.
By midnight, you must be ready for bed.

Action example.
Wait behind the door until Bob walks in.